# xcode 15 crashes as soon as it runs on ios 17

Tags: xcode, appium, ios17, xcode15

I have an iPhone 14 with iOS 17.2 and I had problems running xcode. I saw a lot of comments saying to comment the line, I commented and it makes the automation running (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOSek.jpg)

But when I try to run something, xcode goes down
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMJx0.png)

This only happens to me with iOS 17, I have an iPhone 14 with iOS 16.3 and it doesn't give me any problems.

I tried to downgrade my iPhone but I can't. And the iPhone already comes with iOS 17